# Warning: Prop `className` did not match in NextJs project and classnames package

Tags: next.js

Hi all I'm getting an error Warning: `Prop "className" did not match` somewhere in the code below I believe. I'm using NextJs and CSS Modules and the 'classnames' package. Any ideas, please.

The full error is
`Warning: Prop "className" did not match. Server: "Nav_nav__item__1iofp" Client: "Nav_nav__item__1iofp Nav_nav__itemActive__3cmo3"`

Is it something to do with the `classnames` package allowing two styles to be added when the `router.asPath === link.path` ?

```
{Links.map((link, i) => {
                            return (
                                <li
                                    key={i}
                                    className={
                                        router.asPath === link.path
                                            ? cx(
                                                    styles.nav__item,
                                                    styles.nav__itemActive
                                              )
                                            : styles.nav__item
                                    }>
                                    <Link href={link.path}>{link.name}</Link>
                                </li>
                            );
                        })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What devs suggest [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7322)

A. Delete .next build folder

B. Restart your server

How I am using `className`

```
<p className={styles.description}>Hello</p>
```

Comment: That worked thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For this issue in next js,

I have created a file NoSSr.js with the below code

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const NoSsr = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSsr), { ssr: false });
```

and wrap your layout.js/page.js/index.js with the NoSsr tag

```
<NoSsr>
    <Header />
        <Container maxW={"8xl"}>
            <main>{children}</main>
        </Container>
    <Footer />
</NoSsr>
```